# Make certain routes inaccessible outside react-native app

Tags: laravel, react-native

I have a react-native app that communicates with a laravel backend. I need to be sure that the backend routes are only ever accessed by the mobile app and never from a web browser or curl requests. Bottomline, i want the routes to inaccessible outside of my react native app.

How can i make sure that the routes are only accessible from the android react native app in laravel?.

Comment: You can add a header to all requests you make from your react app and then create a middleware in laravel to check for the presence of the header. then add that middleware to all routes requiring this check.

Comment: Oh wow, great idea. I did not think i can have my own custom http headers. Thanks.